# Hi, i have a List View containing a multiple line text column (6 lines) with append changes to the end selected,

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web, apps-development

I have an Edit Item Form for a list in Sharepoint that i want to change in Sharepoint Designer, to remove 2 fields from the form that the user should not change.
I believe i have to change HTML code to remove the two fields.
The fields i have in List1 are a1, a2, a3, a4 (ID OM), a5 (Responsavel)
I wish to remove a4 and a5 from the editing form (they are Lookup fields) of this list. The user should not change them,
Can anybody tell me how to do this?
[image: edit form]
thanks

Comment: Sorry the title was not corrected - please refer to the body of this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom edit form in SPD and set this as the default edit form.

Once done, go into the edit form on your browser > edit page > edit the form webpart using the xml editor.

You can either remove the rows entirely by deleting the html for the table rows that contain these two fields, or change the XML so that it shows the display value instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is as follows;

- Go to the list app from the Site Content page
- Click *List* on the menu bar then *List Settings*
- Click *Advanced Settings*
- Select *Yes* to *Allow management of content types*; click OK
- Under *Content Types* click the content Type
  [image]
- Select the column you wish to hide and change *Column Settings* to *Hidden*
  [image]

Now when you edit or add a new item these fields will not be visible. You will still be able to see them in a list-view.